# how do i show a jqueryUI at a dynamic location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to show a jquery dialog next to a button when its clicked.

i have:

```
<input type="button" name="test" value="i" 
onclick="$('<div></div>').html('test message').dialog(
{title: 'Test Dialog',modal: false, width: 200, height:140, resizable:false});" 
/>
```

i dont think I can make a function call within a json definition?

I can get the location of the mouse using jquery (from the event) and i am happy to use that as display position or the position of the button.

any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if possible do this outside your markup, it's much easier, so this:

```
<input type="button" name="test" value="i" 
onclick="$('<div></div>').html('test message').dialog(
{title: 'Test Dialog',modal: false, width: 200, height:140, resizable:false});" 
/>
```

Would be:

```
<input type="button" name="test" value="i" />
```

With this script:

```
$(function() {
  $("input[name='test']").click(function() {
    $('<div></div>').html('test message')
       .dialog({title: 'Test Dialog',
                modal: false, 
                width: 200, 
                height:140, 
                resizable:false});
  });
});
```

---

Then we can add positioning, say you want it to the right of the button, then use [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to get the button's position, then add it's [`.outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) to make it appear on the right, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("input[name='test']").click(function() {
    var pos = $(this).offset(),
        top = pos.top - $(document).scrollTop(); //minus amount scrolled down
    $('<div></div>').html('test message')
       .dialog({title: 'Test Dialog',
                modal: false, 
                width: 200, 
                height:140, 
                position: [pos.left + $(this).width(), top],
                resizable:false});
  });
});
```

[You can try an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/aCEea/), it has the exact markup and code that I have above, and [here's a test version to ensure it works with scrolling](http://jsfiddle.net/aCEea/1/).

Comment: This is excellent thanks for the concise code and great link with the example!

However these buttons will be displayed in a table.  I am generating the HTML in ASP (argh!) and I will have an unknown number of these buttons and the content will be specific to the row.

does the square bracket notation allow you to put javascript into JSON? if so when is it executed?

there may be a way i could do it with that

Comment: I Have modifed this code to work inline (generated by ASP) thanks very much.